# How to reconcile time dilation in relativity with what you actually see?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, time

> If a traveler is moving at $0.5c$ towards a clock which is located one light year away, his relativistic time dilation is $1.15$. But in the time he takes to arrive at the clock, he must catch up the 1-year lag that he saw when the clock was 1 light year away, in 2 years travel time. This means he must see the clock moving at twice its normal speed, not $1.15$.

What am I doing wrong?

Why was this question marked as "unclear"? I don't know how else to ask it.
If this question is so unclear, then how is it that I got three perfectly clear answers?
Anyway, thanks to those who took the time to answer.

Apparently, what I was doing wrong was to ask what I was doing wrong? Go figure.
No, this isn't my homework, as I have not attended any university since 1999.

Comment: Your question asks "What am I doing wrong?" which is typical of homework-like and check-my-work questions. Having this phrase in your question makes it highly prone to close and down votes.

Comment: It's unclear to me what is meant by "classical time dilation." Before Relativity, had anybody ever heard of time dilation?

Comment: This is a really important question that is usually glossed over when discussing applications of the Lorentz Transform. I have edited the title to emphasise this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are being downvoted unfairly.  Your answer is logically OK (in the sense that there is more to it than just the Lorentz Transform), but the calculation is wrong.  Use the [doppler effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Doppler_effect#Relativistic_longitudinal_Doppler_effect), and you will see the clock appearing to move $\sqrt {1.5 / 0.5}$ times (1.73) normal speed as you approach (it will also appear to run slower - by a factor of $\sqrt {0.5 / 1.5}$ - if you recede at 0.5$c$).

Comment: Oh good! And 1.73/1.15 (the Lorenz factor) = 1.5, just as expected! Thanks for tolerating my ignorance. I also can't imagine why anyone would deign to downvote this, imho, very sensible question.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you're trying to calculate this by multiplying time intervals by the [Lorentz factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_factor), $\gamma$. And you're ignoring length contraction. To do this properly, you need to use the full [Lorentz transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation).

Don't mix up what each observer measures & calculates with what they observe; observations include the time delay due to the finite speed of light. Determine what are the important [events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_(relativity)) in your scenario, and calculate their time & space coordinates in each frame.

BTW, if two frames $S_1$ and $S_2$ have a relative speed of $v$, so
$$\gamma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$
then each frame measures the other's clock to be ticking *slower* by the $\gamma$ factor.

Comment: I don't think this answer addresses the OP's concerns.

Comment: @m4r35n357 It addresses the OP's mistakes, which is a more important thing to do. Then the OP has something deeper to think about and can address the *specific* concerns.

Comment: @BillN one of the OP's "mistakes" is to use the Lorenz Transform in a situation where the Doppler effect is the correct approach (in other words, whenever the word "see" comes into the question!).  IMO the question just screams "Doppler effect".

Answer (score 2):

There are three separate physical effects that relate directly to the passage or perception of time in SR, and almost every misconception or so-called paradox of SR arises where people have either confused the three effects or overlooked one or more of them. The three effects are as follows:

Time dilation. This arises where one clock moves between two other synchronised clocks that are stationary relative to each other. The passage of time on the moving clock is always less than the difference in readings between the first clock it has passed and the second.

The relativity of simultaneity. This is time dilation viewed from a different perspective. As a moving clock passes a series of stationary clocks which are synchronised in their own frame, the clocks will appear to be increasingly out of synch to the clock that is passing them.

The Doppler effect This arises where a clock is being viewed (or sending signals to) a distant observer who is moving relative to it. If the observer moves towards the clock, it will be 'blue-shifted' which means that it will appear to tick more frequently- if the observer is moving away, the clock will appear to be ticking more slowly.

These three effects all need to be taken into account, and distinguished so that the impact of one is not confused for the impact of another.

In the example you give, all three effects are at play. Suppose you had a friend, moving at the same speed as you and with a synchronised clock, who was present at the distant clock at the time you started your countdown. Likewise, suppose the owner of the distance clock had a friend who was stationary relative to it and standing next to you when you began your journey. Then the effects will work as follows:

The distant clock will seem to you, as you approach it, to be ticking more quickly than once per second, owing to the Doppler effect.

When you arrive at the distant clock, the time that has passed on your own clock will seem less than the time recorded for your journey by the owner of the distant clock and his friend who was present at your departure.

Your friend, who was at the distant clock when you set out, will tell you that the distant clock was showing the wrong time at the outset.

In the example you cite, you must use the relativity of simultaneity to work out what the time is in your frame at the distant clock when you start your journey, and you must consider Doppler effects to determine how the frequency of the distant clock will appear to be running fast as you approach it.

Comment: "These three effects all need to be taken into account, and distinguished so that the impact of one is not confused for the impact of another." - It is only very rarely that separating these effects is desirable, or even possible.

Comment: It depends upon what you mean by possible. On this website all kinds of misconceptions are not just possible but commonplace.