# The effects of light needing to reach observers from observed objects

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light

I know some special relativity, but the material that I've learned has always treated observers as being able to instantly view objects. In reality, the light from an object first needs to travel to the observer. Doesn't this additional time cause some additional effects?

Imagine observer A stands on Earth, while observer B leaves Earth with speed $v$, travels to some point distance $L$ away (distance $L$ according to A), and returns.

Assume that $v$ is very close to $c$. What does A then observe? When he sees B at the midpoint $L/2$, B is actually very nearly at $L$. $B$ then reaches $L$, and starts the return journey. On this return journey, $B$ travels slightly behind the light he emits. Hence A will see the return in a very short burst, and see B travel at a speed far larger than $c$. Also, A will see B travel at a speed of slightly more than $v/2$ during the outbound journey, since he sees $B$ at $L/2$ when he is actually nearly at $L$.

I've tried to put this mathematically: Let $x(t)$ be the distance at which A sees B at time $t$. A sees where B was a period of time of $x/c$ earlier, since this is the time it takes light to traverse the distance. So we get
\begin{align}
x&=v\left(t-\frac{x}{c}\right)=vt-\frac{v}{c}x \\
\Longrightarrow x&=\frac{v}{1+\frac{v}{c}}t \\
\Longrightarrow v'&=\frac{v}{1+\frac{v}{c}}
\end{align}
where $v'$ is the observed velocity.

This sounds extremely fantastical and I've never heard of this, so is this really what happens, or have I made some mistake and this is yet another false relativistic paradox? I know that B will see himself traveling a distance of only $L/\gamma$ and that simultaneity is not the same for the two observers, but I don't see how this matters, as (hopefully) I've only been considering the situation from A's point of view and haven't mixed the two POVs together.

Comment: *Doesn't this additional time cause some additional effects?* Yes, it does. [Terrell rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrell_rotation)

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/646666/123208

Comment: *"[...] has always treated observers as being able to instantly view objects"* That's unfortunate. A better approach is to consider that an inertial frame is equipped with a lattice of synchronised clocks, eg https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/514964/123208 & https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/659986/123208

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of the teaching of relativity is awful, and a common problem in text books is that they are written in a way that blurs the meaning of the word observer. As you point out, a literal observer cannot immediately see events that are far away without waiting for the light from the event. Often text books sloppily use the word observer to mean a reference frame, so you just need to be on the look-out for that kind of loose talk.

To take up your example, the observer on Earth would see the traveller red-shifted (slowed down) on the way out and blue-shifted (speeded up) on the way back. The fact that the traveller appears back on Earth not long after the arrival of the light from the turnaround point is not a problem, since the traveller was never actually travelling faster than light. What a distant observer literally sees, and what actually happens, are two different things.

Comment: OK thanks, "use the word observer to mean a reference frame" is exactly the phrase I was looking for! Just to clarify, is everything I said in my question really what happens?

Comment: Cheers! I haven't checked your maths (I'm too old for maths!) but your logic sounds fine. Look up the relativistic Doppler effect, and that should tell you all you need to know, but please come back to me if it doesn't.